# Armature Parenting Issue

Tags: rigging, objects, bones, parent

Dear Blender Community ,
    I am struggling to solve an issue concerning parenting an armature to another object (so I don't have to animate it separately. In this instance I'm trying to have my 'l' in slavery to be able to hold a pickaxe. The only problem is as the 'I' deforms back upwards to its resting position, the pickaxe stays stuck inside the rock. Do you guys[image] have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand everything going on, but if it's a problem with the whole armature, you could try parenting bone to your object. Then make that bone the parent bone. 
Or you could try the child of constraint.